# What would total cost of the LEGO® Star Wars collection be in MSRP to date? [Dec 2015]

Tags: lego-group, star-wars, value

According to [this article from 2014](http://www.wired.com/2014/02/infoporn-legos/), the cost to buy the entire LEGO® Star Wars collection since 1999 would have been just under $15,000 USD ($14,762). I *assume* the price mentioned in this article is calculated based on original MSRP, not inflated resale or in-store sale values.

Using MSRP as the baseline for all sets across time, what would the current sum total be of the entire Star Wars licensed collection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to data collected from Brickset, the total MSRP of all Star Wars sets to date is $18,933.76 USD. This includes a total of 508 sets. I simply used the CSV export feature on Brickset to put this together.

Here's the raw data if you'd like to explore it further:

https://gist.github.com/jncraton/68beb88e6027d9321373

Comment: I did not realize there was a CSV option like this, super useful. +1 and accepted! I'd give you more upvotes if I could for providing that raw data for review as well! #TIL